# dynamic sql query issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Suppose I have threw columns in some table `time`, `campaign_id`, `campaign_scale`. I want to compute the global time of campaign, each of which depends dynamically of a function of the `campaign_id`, this function `my_func($campaign_id)` so I put

```
select sum(time *
                CASE
                  WHEN campaign_scale = 2
                     THEN 1
                  WHEN campaign_scale = 1
                    THEN '. my_func().'
                  ELSE '.(my_func(()/7).'
                END
                ) as sum
                    from table where id = :id'); // then I bind the `id` value
```

But here I can't figure out how I can pass the `campaign_id` parameter to each row. Could someone help ?

Comment: What function/lib are you using to run the query? PDO, mysqli_*, any ORM..?

Comment: @Isouza I am using PDO

Comment: could you edit your post and add the part of the code where you try to run the select?

Comment: @Isouza, it would be quite long and it has absolutely no relation with my problem since I ran this query with `my_func(1)` as param, and it worked

Comment: Is the function defined in MySQL or php?  You can only call functions defined in the database within a query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it is a function defined in PHP...

Comment: @GordonLinoff, this what you say remains true if I want to apply to each row some built-in php function such as `strototime` ?

Comment: @user1611830 . . .  You would instead use the MySQL function `str_to_date()`.  Otherwise, you need to bring the data back, read the result set one by one and call the function you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry to bother you again, what else if I manage my thing to only need to multiply each row by some scalar. Is that possible ? my_func(campaign_id) would become `21*campaign_id`

Comment: You can do that in the database too.